# I need to get the second last row in a table in database

Tags: python, sql

I have this code to print the values of columns of the last row but I need to check the second last row. I tried a lot of methods with (fetchall(),...etc) but i didn't get the target result
Can anyone help me to get the second last row in a table that i don't know the number of its lines?
Thank you in advance.

```
    colnames = [desc[0] for desc in self.cursor.description]
    coltypes = [desc[1] for desc in self.cursor.description]
    columns_nb= len(colnames)
    result = self.cursor.fetchone()
    self.close_database_connection()
    if result:
        for i in range(columns_nb):
            colname = colnames[i]
            coltype = coltypes[i]
            rows_value = result[i]
            rows_values.append(rows_value)
            row_data_dict[column_name] = [ rows_value, coltype ]
            self.logger.debug("Column {} values : {}"\
                              .format(colname , result[i]))
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is not such thing as the "last row" in a table, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **ORDER BY** clause to get the second last row of a table:

The syntax is as follows.

select *from **yourTableName** order by **yourColumnName** DESC LIMIT 1,1;

To understand the above syntax, let us create a table. The query to create a table is as follows.

```
mysql> create table secondLastDemo
   -> (
   -> StudentId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   -> StudentName varchar(10)
   -> );
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.52 sec)

Insert some records in the table using the **insert** command.

The query is as follows.

```
**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Larry');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Carol');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Bob');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Sam');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Mike');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('David');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Maxwell');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Robert');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.13 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('James');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.14 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Chris');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.11 sec)**

**mysql> insert into secondLastDemo(StudentName) values('Ramit');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)******
```

Display all records from the table using **select** statement.

The query is as follows.

```
****mysql> select *from secondLastDemo;****
```

The following is the output.

```
**+-----------+-------------+
| StudentId | StudentName |
+-----------+-------------+
| 1         | Larry       |
| 2         | Carol       |
| 3         | Bob         |
| 4         | Sam         |
| 5         | Mike        |
| 6         | David       |
| 7         | Maxwell     |
| 8         | Robert      |
| 9         | James       |
| 10        | Chris       |
| 11        | Ramit       |
+-----------+-------------+
```

11 rows in set (0.00 sec)**

Here is the query to get the second last row of a table in MySQL.

```
****mysql> select *from secondLastDemo order by StudentId DESC LIMIT 1,1;****

**+-----------+-------------+
| StudentId | StudentName |
+-----------+-------------+
| 10        | Chris       |
 +-----------+-------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)**
The output displays the **second last record**.